# How to create Enterprise Architect packages, classes, attributes programmatically

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am trying to use/understand Interop.EA and EA class in C# and how to create diagrams programmatically.

I'm working with user data (.XML file (not XMI)) from another web application.

I have tried [CSAddinDemo](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/autint.html) from Sparx and it works fine, but does not show how to add/create new.

My goal is to create EA class diagram form XML data, in C#.

Something like this??

```
public void EA_create()
{
    EA.DiagramObject d = new DiagramObject();
    EA.Element e = new Element();

    EA.Element elementEa = EA.Element.AddNew("Requirement", "non-functional");
    elementEa.Update();
    elements.Refresh();
    //MessageBox.Show("Class created");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, you need an EA project (aka "repository") to work in. In order to create a new EA project (.EAP file), use `Repository.CreateModel()`. In order to open an existing one, use `Repository.OpenFile()`.

Other than the `Repository` class, which is the top-level class for all interactions with EA, you don't create objects yourself. Instead, you call `AddNew()` on the various `Collections` you traverse -- this goes for packages, elements, diagrams, diagram objects, connectors, attributes, tagged values, etc etc.

`Repository.Models` is such a collection (of `Packages`).

A `Package` then contains additional collections, such as `Packages`, `Elements` and `Diagrams`. A `Diagram` has a collection of `DiagramObjects`.

A `DiagramObject` is the graphical representation of an element within one (1) diagram (remember that an element is *stored* in exactly one package but can be *shown* in any number of diagrams).

EA does not allow you to create any diagrams or elements at the top level of the package tree (called the root node); you must first create a child package. So at the very least you need to create one `Package` and one `Diagram`, a number of `Elements` and one `DiagramObject` for each element.

So in the code you've got, `AddNew()` doesn't work because you're trying to call it on an `Element` and you need to call it on a `Collection`.

Your use of `Update()` and `Refresh()` are correct, assuming that `elements` is a `Collection`. You must always call Update after any changes to an object, and Refresh after any changes to a collection.

There's some good getting-started stuff in the help file. Look in *Automation and Scripting -- Enterprise Architect Object Model*, and read the section titled *Using the Automation Interface*.

Then, look at *Reference -- Code Samples*, especially *Open the Repository* and *Add and Manage Diagrams*.

Finally, note that an Add-In is a piece of code which extends EA and is run from within an EA process. This isn't necessary if you want to create a new model or make changes to an existing one; you only need to write an Add-In if you want to integrate with EA's GUI or respond to various events triggered by EA.